# Control component states from App.js and change their values

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, addeventlistener, dom-events

I have an IOT application that communicates with ble devices. So I use `react-native-ble-manager`.

In this package, you have to use event listeners such as;

```
bleManagerEmitter.addListener( 'BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic', this.handlerCharListenerSettings);
```

(For more information you can check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ble-manager))

So I use these event listeners in different screens, but it's not a proper way. Because In every screen that has event listener loads this `addListener` and this causes problems. In `componentWillUnmount` event you can clear these listeners, but the correct way is to control all these listeners on one logical place such as App.js or anywhere similar.

My problem begins here:
I have different screens, I want to set their states from App.js. I mean when I change a value from App.js event listener, I want to make the other screens affected by this value. How I can do this or is this a proper way of using listeners?

My RN version is 0.58

Comment: For global state management you should use Context API or any flux like Redux

Comment: Context API seems to be proper for solving the problem. I will study it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the listener either use the Context API as mentioned or create a wrapping component. Much like the App.js create a new component:

```
    <Wrapper>
      <YourApp/>
    <Wrapper/>

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
     bleManagerEmitter.addListener( 'BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic', this.handlerCharListenerSettings);
   }
}
```